# Is there a way to iterate over my train features?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How can I load data of shape:

```
X_train : (4864,6989)
X_test : (2085, 6989)
y_train : (4864, 270)
y_test : (2005, 270)
```

into the memory? I have 16 GB of RAM.

What I have tried:

1. Loading data in chunks

   `extracted_df = pd.read_csv("ExtractedData.csv", chunksize=6953)`
2. Using virtual memory (paging) by going in the system settings
3. Reducing the chunk size even further.
4. Not too sure about how to use a batch generator.

My data has 98k rows and 2 columns. Even after chunking, I can't fit the data in memory. How can I iterate over the X_train and y_train to make it even smaller? Say 100 rows per iteration? Perhaps something like:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data, train_labels, shuffle=True, test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
for iterator in X_train.shape[0]:
     estimator.fit(iterator, y_train)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
def pos_tag(docs):
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    tagged_sentences = []
    for item in docs:
        combined = []
        tagged = nlp(item)
        for token in tagged:
            combined.append('_'.join([token.lemma_, token.pos_]))
        combined_string = ' '.join(combined)
        tagged_sentences.append(combined_string)
    return tagged_sentences


def encode_data(docs):
    tokenizer = text.Tokenizer(num_words=75000)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(docs)
    tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(docs)
    docs = sequence.pad_sequences(tokenized)
    return docs

print("Tagging...")
    docs = pos_tag(docs)
    print("Creating features")
    nn_list = []
    vb_list = []
    for sentence in docs:
        nns = 0
        vbs = 0
        elements = sentence.split('_')
        for item in elements:
            if item == 'NOUN':
                nns += 1
            if item == 'VERB':
                vbs += 1
        nn_list.append(nns)
        vb_list.append(vbs)
    nn_list = np.array(nn_list).reshape(-1, 1)
    vb_list = np.array(vb_list).reshape(-1, 1)

    print("Encoding data...")
    docs_encoded = encode_data(docs)
    docs_encoded = np.array(docs_encoded)
    docs_encoded = np.append(docs_encoded, nn_list, axis=1)
    docs_encoded = np.append(docs_encoded, vb_list, axis=1)
    labels = np.array(labels)
    train_data = docs_encoded.astype(int)
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(labels)
    encoded_labels = encoder.transform(labels)
    train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_labels)
```

Comment: What is that data, where does it come from? I feel that we're missing some information here.

Comment: The data is one-hot encoded (text to numerical). It is being loaded into the memory using pd.read_csv(). Please see the updated question. Any help will be greatly appreciated.